# Mysql: what to use instead of WITH statement or TEMPORARY tables?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

Is there a way to store a select query into a table? I usually work with the WITH statement
but this is only possible with mysql 8+. I am currently using mysql 5.1. Therefore I tried to implement a temporary table but it is not possible to refer to a temporary table more than once in the same query (like the query below).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test
SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, MAX(L.period), CURDATE()) as timediff, L.contractID 
FROM license L GROUP BY L.contractID;

UPDATE `contract` AS C
SET C.valid = CASE
WHEN (SELECT timediff FROM test AS T WHERE T.contractID = C.contractID) < 1 THEN 2
WHEN (SELECT timediff FROM test AS T WHERE T.contractID = C.contractID) = 1 THEN 1
WHEN (SELECT timediff FROM test AS T WHERE T.contractID = C.contractID) > 1 THEN 0
END;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE test;
```

Comment: You don't need a temp table at all here, just use a *derived table* for the *license* query and join to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could immediately remedy your problem by phrasing the update as a join:

```sql
UPDATE contract c
INNER JOIN test t
    ON t.contractID = c.contractID
SET valid = CASE WHEN t.timediff < 1 THEN 2
                 WHEN t.timediff = 1 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END;
```

This approach gets around the problem of referring to the temporary table more than once.

Comment: Awesome. That is a great workaround and looks a lot better !